# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?', its list not an object, why dart says its an object?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var jobs = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Unemployment',
      'salary': '0',
      'skills': ['Math', 'Social'],
    },
];
```

I want to get first value of skills object inside first jobs list, but i've got

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver
> can be 'null'. (view docs) Try making the call conditional (using
> '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')

is it an object ? because every time I'm running `print(jobs[0]['skills'][0]);` it always return

> Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.   print(jobs[1]['skills'][0]);
>   ^ Error: Compilation failed.

Comment: `jobs[0]['skills']`'s *runtime* type is a `List`, but at compilation time, the compiler only sees that you have a `Map` of `String`s to heterogeneous values, so it picks the common base type for the values when inferring the type (`Map<String, Object>`).  If you want the `Map` values to be `dynamic`, you be *explicit*: `var jobs = [<String, dynamic>{ ... }];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<dynamic> jobs = <dynamic>[];

 jobs = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Unemployment',
      'salary': '0',
      'skills': ['Math', 'Social'],
    },
];
```

Now Print :

```
print(jobs[0]['skills'][0]);
```

and it should print Math now

Answer (score 1):

As if you know the skills would be an array, you can use typecast (the "as" operator) it to a List as below:

```
print((jobs[0]['skills'] as List<String>).toList().first);
// Math
```